# Dagger 2: @Provides still requires @Inject in constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

As far as I know there are 2 ways to provide an object in Dagger. Via @Provides or @Inject.

```
    @Provides
    @AssetScope
    fun provideAssetRepository(
        interceptor: RequestInterceptor,
        service: CryptoService,
        mapper: AssetDtoMapper
    ): AssetsRepository =
        AssetsRepositoryImpl(
            interceptor,
            service,
            mapper
        ) // Provide interface not implementation for fake test
```

But upon building, it gives an error

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.app.sample.data.repositories.AssetsRepositoryImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Unless I add @Inject in the empty constructor.

```
class AssetsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(...
```

The error won't disappear.

I think I misunderstood how Dagger and `@ContributesAndroidInjector` works. This is my modules and component looks like.

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        CommonModule::class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class,
        ActivityBuildersModule::class,
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    // Override the builder
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

}
```

The Activities

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeSplashActivity(): SplashActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFragmentBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

The Fragments

```
@Module
abstract class MainFragmentBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [HomeModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeHomeFragment(): HomeFragment
    @Module
    abstract inner class HomeModule {
        @AssetScope
        @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [AssetModule::class, AssetViewModelModule::class])
        abstract fun contributeAssetFragment(): AssetFragment

    }

}
```

The module that seems not working

```
@Module
object AssetModule {

    @Provides
    @AssetScope
    fun provideAssetRepository(
        interceptor: RequestInterceptor,
        service: CryptoService,
        mapper: AssetDtoMapper
    ): AssetsRepository =
        AssetsRepositoryImpl(
            interceptor,
            service,
            mapper
        ) // Provide interface not implementation for fake test

}
```

I am expecting that `AssetModule` will provides dependencies on `AssetFragment` but I was wrong. I think it will only work if I put it on `AppModule` or via its `@Module(includes = [])`

Comment: The @Provides have a scope are you sure the scope is correct ?

Comment: @Ruokki probably not

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that `AssetsRepositoryImpl` is requested by some binding.  The offending binding should be named in the next line of the error message.

Your stated goal is to depend on the interface instead of the concrete implementation, so you should change this binding to request `AssetsRepository` instead.